# Cup product in modified (Tate) group hypercohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group.
Let
$$ M^\bullet=\,(\dots\to M^{-1}\to M^0\to M^1\to\dots) $$
be a bounded complex of $G$-modules.
One can define Tate hypercohomology groups $H^n(G,M^\bullet)$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z$.

Let $C$ be a $G$-module and let $\alpha\in H^2(G,C)$ be a cohomology class.
I wish to define a cup-product map
$$H^n(G,M^\bullet)\to H^{n+2}(G, M^\bullet\otimes C),\quad \xi\mapsto\xi\cup\alpha,$$
where
$$ M^\bullet\otimes C=\,(\dots\to M^{-1}\otimes C\to M^0\otimes C\to M^1\otimes C\to\dots)$$
and the tensor product is taken over $\Bbb Z$.
This is known for Tate *cohomology*, but I need it for Tate *hypercohomology*.

I am looking for a reference for the existence of such a cup-product map.
However, if there is no such a reference, I would be happy to get a sketch of a construction.

Comment: If you are willing to have a reference for a very abstract construction of this cup product, in much more general context, it is in Nikolaus-scholze paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01799.pdf theorem I.3.1. Of course, that would be a total over-kill, but it gives in particular the cup product that you'r after very cleanly. Of course, if you want a formula in terms of resolutions or something, then you need to specify how you implement Tate hypercohomology to get an answer in an explicit form., and there must be older and more down to earth refs to this.

Comment: Thank you, @S.carmeli! There is a paper [Koya, Yoshihiro:
A generalization of class formation by using hypercohomology.
Invent. Math. 101 (1990), no. 3, 705–715](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01231522), where the required assertion  is stated without proof. Together with the reference to Nikolaus and Scholze, this will be sufficient.